# How to make my program wait till batch file execution finishes

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In my application, I am invoking a batch file which is applying some business logic and creating one zip file.

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "cmd /c start " + myBatchFile + " " + inputProjectPath + " " + outputProjectDirectory);
int a = process.waitFor();
```

Now my application has to read that file and do some operation on it. But even after using `waitFor()`, the program execution is not waiting for the batch-file to complete it's execution so that it can read a correct file. Please help me resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get rid of the `start`.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for quick response. If I got your answer correct, then removing `start` from the string parameter of process.execute() is not opening the command prompt.

Comment: Add the `/w` switch to the `start` command. Also note that the first quoted parameter to a `start` is assigned as the window-title. Commonly, `start /w "" "actual command..." ...` is used to obviate this characteristic.

Comment: Incorrect. It will execute CMD, which will execute the batch file inline. See the documentation. By using START you are causing the batch file to be executed asynchronously from the CMD you started, which is not what you state you want. So don't do that.

Comment: Get rid of start or you can use call, but that is typically the same as just removing start. `"cmd /c " + myBatchFile + "` or `"cmd /c call " + myBatchFile + "`

Comment: @EJP Correct! removing `start` did work. Actually it is executing the batch file in background without CMD perhaps as CMD is not getting opened up but the batch file is running fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Please clarify 'typically'. In what atypical cases isn't it true?

Comment: @EJP perhaps the term 'typical' was a little broad. It was aimed more in general, call in a batch behaves differently when it experiences fatal errors and control might not be handed back to the caller window, that is the only real reason I used the term, hope that makes sense.

Comment: can you send complete method ?